# How to declare a subclass of EventEmitter?

Tags: typescript

I am writing type definitions for JS code in `types.d.ts` and I want to declare a class that subclasses `EventEmitter`, but it won't let me:

```
type EventEmitter = import('events').EventEmitter

// 'EventEmitter' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
declare class Foo extends EventEmitter {}
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE: As a workaround, I copied the nodejs.eventemitter `interface` definition into my types.d.ts, and changed `interface` to `declare class`, and it works. Is this a bug in the NodeJS typing?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] Changing the import I don't get an error

```js
import type {EventEmitter} from 'events'

declare class Foo extends EventEmitter {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAuE8AcFMAIFEBu0B2p4FsCWpTQE6wC8sWGkA9vqABQDk0yaAznQJQB0Sq62uBAKDKVqsCDFgBvbmkw48+AL6wAZvgoZYDJqFYCBILTN7yCdWBRQAbcLHzQVBZmIqwAhmKjQANLABGAK6gpM5+0FgoAOawAczQACbuzh6IblYBcAAWBNAcujQATABsAJwAzGwC8dAAxlZu9rB1bszOAGIUrtAAHngo8c7GcvyEkopAA)

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see in the playground, that causes complaints that Bar doesn't implement all the methods EventEmitter has :-(

Comment: this won't work in a type declaration file because you can't import in types.d.ts :(